# Retain file value in <input type="file">

Tags: php, html

This is my HTML code:

```
<input style="margin-left:10px;" type="file"
name="user_upload_image" class="uploader" id="file" value="<?php
        if(isset($_POST['user_upload_image'])) {
            echo $_POST['user_upload_image'];
        }
?>"">
```

This code is not making the image stay in the box after the form is refreshed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For setting its value then well its not possible.

The reason you can not set the value is a **security issue**. Imagine if you
could set it. The page loads, sets the value, then autosubmits the form.
I could gain any file on your computer I wanted, that I know the path to.

[Read More](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/266087)

Comment: Explain? Your answer was _completely_ wrong and irrelevant. The fact that you've edited your answer entirely and ask this is beyond me, since you clearly already know the answer. Unfortunately, as good as your answer might now be, my downvote is locked in and cannot be removed.

Comment: @DannyBeckett yes i was wrong before but i at that time i was updating my answer and i thought i down-voted for this updated answer...sorry do not take it personally calm down...humm did not removed down-vote yet..

Comment: I told you, I can't remove it. Votes get locked in after about 5 mins.

Comment: dnt worry.. I upvoted it.. but as far as my question is concerned hw can I make it stay on page

Comment: @aks: The answer is still **you can't**.

Comment: @DannyBeckett see again i am late too read comments...you told you removed down-vote and then you change comment...hahaha...good

Comment: @aks you can not, you can just display only name of the previously uploaded file if its in edit mode...

Answer (score 0):

You can't retain an `<input>` of `type="file"`.

Comment: that means on refreshing a page there is no option of retaining user input or path of file upload? he has to do it again anyhow?

Comment: @aks Store the image on the server, then pull it back down, if your page needs to refresh for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that. Upload the image to server then show the thumbnail of the image there.

If you want to show the image before submitting the form, use AJAX and upload image to server then show it near your "browse" button. You can not show the path in side the file text box